# Tool for bulk svg optimization

Tags: web-apps, web-services, graphic-design, svg

I am looking for an svg online tool where I can upload / download multiple svgs at once and reduce the file size. Something like tinypng.com but for SVGs.

I need the following features:

- Remove ids
- Remove classes
- Remove whitespace
- Remove styles
- Remove empty elements
- Remove redundant shapes
- Remove clean group
- Apply transforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a tool that meets my requirements!

https://vecta.io/nano